# crossdomain.xml

Tags: actionscript

подключаю так:

```
Security.allowDomain('http://85.95.163.90');
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://85.95.163.90/vk_pc/crossdomain.xml");
```

но

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://85.95.163.90/vk_pc/game.php"));
```

не работает.

crossdomain.xml:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

что не так?

UPD:

[image]

Comment: Так вы не с браузером работаете?

Comment: Почитайте тут - http://www.flasher.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=125411

Comment: Если запускаете SWF на десктопе, лучше соберите AIR приложение, там нет запретов на кроссдоменную политику безопасности.

Comment: я просто тестю тут т.к. он выводит информацию об ошибки. А в браузере просто не грузит данные.

Comment: В браузере стоит не дебаг версия, поэтому не выводит ошибку. Вот тут выводит - http://oxanaratone.narod.ru/assault/test00.html

Эта флешка стучится на ваш сервер и грузит хмл с выводом, ошибки тоже печатает.

Comment: спасибо большое. оказалось что в браузере всё работает просто не отображается. Я хотел увидеть данные при дебаге в FL но они почемута там вообще не отображаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все работает, код такой:

```
protected function executeTest():void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://85.95.163.90/vk_pc/game.php'); 
    loader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler, false, 0, true);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
    loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
    loader.load (req);
}

protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
     trace( event.target.data );
}

private function errorHandler(event:Event):void 
{
    trace("Error: " + event);
}
```

Еще проверьте правильность кросдомена, в идеале должно быть так:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```